# Value of type 'error' has no member 'userinfo'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

My code is as follows:

```
if signupMode {
    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = emailTextField.text
    user.email = emailTextField.text
    user.password = passwordTextField.text
    user.signUpInBackground(block: {
       (success, error) in

if error != nil {

    let displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later"

    if let errorMessage = error.UserInfo["error"]? as String {
        displayErrorMessage = errorMessage                
    }

self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Parse Error")
}
```

I just keep getting the error

> "value of type 'error' has no member 'userinfo"

What can I do to fix this? I'm using Xcode 8

Comment: if signupMode {
                let user = PFUser()
                user.username = emailTextField.text
                user.email = emailTextField.text
                user.password = passwordTextField.text
                user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        if let errorMessage = error.UserInfo["error"]? as String {
                           // displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
                    }  
                        self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Parse Error")
                    }

Comment: Sorry Im not actually sure that was helpful!

Comment: `if let error = error as? NSError {  ... use error here }`

Answer (score 2):

If you're still getting this error, try this code. Force unwrap error as NSError.

```
if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {
    displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By your snipped it can't be determined what `error` is and wether it should have a member called `UserInfo`. Please provide more code...

I assume it is an [NSError](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror/1411580-userinfo)? In this case it would be `error.userInfo` as member name. (watch the casing)

Other than that your code will fail compiling because you declare `let displayErrorMessage` but in the if make an assignment to it. You would need to change it to `var displayErrorMessage` to be able to do that.

Try this:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
      // Perform a segue, show a message or whatever you want

    } else {
      let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have also changed the let to var! Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer based on you code. Does that help?

Comment: You need to cast from Swift 3 Error to NSError

Comment: Try `((error as Any) as! NSError).userInfo["error"]`